# How to solve or identify problems in Neural Networks which can be seen on Tensorboard Graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I my own data set created by me with 5000 data points. Using those data I built up a network to train with one 1 hidden layers.

- input layer contains 3 input neurons
- Hidden layer has 100 neurons
- output layer has 3 neurons

I used tangent-sigmoid(tanh) activation function for hidden neurons and liner activation function for output layer. I used tensor board to visualize the result for accuracy and loss.

Problem is my graphs (look at the figure) is very fuzzy and meaning less. And i wont get a accuracy more than 40%. And the network doesn't seem like leaning.

my assumption is, *there is a problem in my data input method. Please help me out.*

```
import random
import math
import csv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard


linkLength = 2
def Xe (a,b,c):
    return linkLength*math.cos(a)+linkLength*math.cos(a+b)+linkLength*math.cos(a+b+c)
def Ye (e,f,g):
    return linkLength*math.sin(e) + linkLength*math.sin(e + f) + linkLength*math.sin(e + f + g)
def tita (h,i,j):
      return math.degrees(h)+math.degrees(i)+math.degrees(j)

Q1 = []
Q2 = []
Q3 = []
posX = []
posY = []
titaEnd = []

# data set creation 
for i in range (0,5000):
    q1= round(random.uniform(0,math.pi),2)
    q2= round(random.uniform(-math.pi,0),2)
    q3= round(random.uniform(-math.pi/2, math.pi/2), 2)
    Q1.append(q1)
    Q2.append(q2)
    Q3.append(q3)
    posX.append(Xe(q1,q2,q3))
    posY.append(Ye(q1,q2,q3))
    titaEnd.append(tita(q1,q2,q3))



for i in range(0,len(posX)):
    plt.plot([posX[i],posX[i]+0.2*math.cos(math.radians(titaEnd[i]))],[posY[i],posY[i]+0.2*math.sin(math.radians(titaEnd[i]))],'k-')

plt.scatter(posX,posY)
plt.xlabel("X Axis")
plt.ylabel("Y Axis")
plt.title("data set of 1000 possible endeffector positions and orientations")
plt.show()
dataMat =np.c_[Q1,Q2,Q3,posX,posY,titaEnd]
#removing duplicated end effeector positions
for i in range (0,4999):
    check1 = dataMat[i,3]
    check2 = dataMat[i,4]
    check3 = dataMat[i,5]
    for j in range (0,4999):
        if i != j:
            #print(i,j,'checking..')
            if (dataMat[j,3] == check1 and dataMat[j,4] == check2 and dataMat[j,5] == check3):
                print(i,j,dataMat[j,3],dataMat[j,4],dataMat[j,5])
#Preprocessing
MinMaxNorm = preprocessing.minmax_scale(dataMat,(-1,1))

plt.scatter(MinMaxNorm[:,3],MinMaxNorm[:,4])
plt.title("Preprocessed data")
plt.show()

#print(MinMaxNorm)

data =MinMaxNorm[:,[3,4,5]]
output =MinMaxNorm[:,[0,1,2]]


#Building NN

random.shuffle(data)
random.shuffle(output)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation ='tanh'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation ='linear'))


NAME = "Trajectry Tracking"
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01),loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])       # mean squared error

model.fit(data,output, epochs=20, batch_size =40, callbacks=[tensorboard])

model.evaluate(data,output)

#_Tensor Board
#tensorboard --logdir=logs/`
```

[image]

Comment: Have you cleaned up your logdir after running your code? If you do not, it can lead to messy overlapping curves.

Comment: Yeh. I always run logdir in python terminal and get a new server address each time i run the code.

Comment: The server adress is irrelevant, I am talking about the actual folder where you store your meta and checkpoint files. Do you delete all files there before running your code?

Comment: No, and i did it now. and it worked. Than you a lot :) plus i found 2 bugs in my code which is limiting getting trained

Comment: (1) The messy graphs appear because of shuffling data, random.shuffle(data) random.shuffle(output) (2) Problem with the Y axis(there are several loss/acc values for a one epoch) comes if you haven't segment data as Train data(80% of the data set), Test data(10% of the data set) and data for evaluation(10% of the data set). when you do these corrections you can get a nice and informative diagrams in tensorboard